# Unable to copy large files to wd mycloud ex2 ultra

Tags: networking, nas

I've just purchased a WD mycloud and find myself having to jump through hoops to transfer files onto it.

Windows is unable to find shared folders on the device via explorer / file sharing services (this might be due to my laptop being part of a domain and not a workgroup) so I'm mounting WD's shared folders via WebDav. When attempting to transfer a large file Windows reports there is too little storage left despite the majority of the two Terabytes still being available.

The WD device connects to my home network via a shared wifi connection. The device itself is connected via ethernet to my laptop.

Upgrading to the latest firmware version has netted no improvement.

Comment: Just because Explorer doesn’t discover the shares doesn’t mean you can access them by connecting directly via name or even IP address.

Comment: I can connect to the device directly using explorer but it seems only via WebDav.

Comment: Why do you assume it's WebDav? Does the WD device have some configuration interface?

Comment: Rather late in the day, but am struggling with networking issues with my MyCloud so thought a comment might be useful to others.

But if I understand your setup you have the MyCloud on a (router-less) direct ethernet connection to your laptop and your laptop is connected to the wider home networ by wifi.

With the MyCloud on a different physical network adapter to the main network  there needs to be a network bridge between them - which you can create from the NetWork & Sharing tools. It does however seem quite trickly to do this while also having network access from the bridging computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a solution when working with WebDav. I was able to transfer the files using windows file networking.